# Could the 'expss' R package be an equivalent of the SAS PROC TABULATE?

Tags: r, expss

With the expss package for R, the following simple code gives the count of cars for each of the crossed values of 'cyl', 'gear', 'am' and 'vs'. Using a similar layout, would it be possible to replace this count by some statistic computed on a fifth variable (e.g. the median of 'mpg')?

```
mtcars %>% 
tab_cells(cyl) %>% 
tab_cols(vs, am) %>% 
tab_rows(gear) %>%
tab_stat_cases() %>% 
tab_pivot()
```

Comment: `tab_stat_median` instead of `tab_stat_cases`?

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understand, you need:

```
mtcars %>% 
    tab_cells(mpg) %>% 
    tab_cols(vs, am) %>% 
    tab_rows(set_var_lab(gear, "gear") %nest% set_var_lab(cyl, "cyl")) %>%
    tab_stat_median() %>% 
    tab_pivot()
```

It gives:

```
 # |      |    |     |    |     |        |   vs |      |   am |      |
 # |      |    |     |    |     |        |    0 |    1 |    0 |    1 |
 # | ---- | -- | --- | -- | --- | ------ | ---- | ---- | ---- | ---- |
 # | gear |  3 | cyl |  4 | mpg | Median |      | 21.5 | 21.5 |      |
 # |      |    |     |  6 | mpg | Median |      | 19.8 | 19.8 |      |
 # |      |    |     |  8 | mpg | Median | 15.2 |      | 15.2 |      |
 # |      |  4 | cyl |  4 | mpg | Median |      | 25.9 | 23.6 | 28.9 |
 # |      |    |     |  6 | mpg | Median | 21.0 | 18.5 | 18.5 | 21.0 |
 # |      |    |     |  8 | mpg | Median |      |      |      |      |
 # |      |  5 | cyl |  4 | mpg | Median | 26.0 | 30.4 |      | 28.2 |
 # |      |    |     |  6 | mpg | Median | 19.7 |      |      | 19.7 |
 # |      |    |     |  8 | mpg | Median | 15.4 |      |      | 15.4 |
```

**UPDATE:**

- tab_rows - row grouping variables
- tab_cols - column grouping variables
- tab_cells - variables on which we calculate statistics. It is rather natural when we calculate summary statistics such as median, mean and etc, but may be confusing when we calculate cases or column percent. You can get some docs by typing `?tab_cells` in the console.

```

```
|         |   tab_cols     |
|tab_rows | stat(tab_cells)|
```

```

For count of cars:

```
mtcars %>% 
    tab_cells(mpg) %>% 
    tab_cols(vs, am) %>% 
    tab_rows(set_var_lab(gear, "gear") %nest% set_var_lab(cyl, "cyl")) %>%
    tab_stat_median() %>% 
    tab_stat_valid_n(label = "#Total") %>% 
    tab_pivot(stat_position = "inside_rows")
```

You can manage number of decimals with `expss_digits()` but it changes the number of decimals for entire table. Or, if you are using RStudio on Windows you can try `expss_output_viewer()` for output in RStudio viewer. In this case rows with "#" will be shown without decimals.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't understand the meaning of tab_cells.

Comment: Actually I also needed nesting on vs and am but it doesn't make an issue. Anyway, thanks. I didn't understand the meaning of tab_cells : is there some document that explains how to assemble the different functions? Examples are not enough to understand the logic. Additional question : if I want both the median of mpg and the count of cars (one following the other, and the count without decimals)?  .

Comment: Thanks again. I eventually got rid of the unwanted decimals using a linear layout of the statistics,with  tab_stat_fun(Median = w_median, N = w_n,method=list)